# String in a formula in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula

I'm struggling to a string in iferror function in the following code. i want string to be variable and a input box pops up for the string specifying what the user wants if an error pops up.

```
Sub test_IFERROR()
Dim frange As Range, xcell As Range
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set frange = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not frange Is Nothing Then
    xStr = Application.InputBox("Replace blank cells with what?", "Kutools for Excel")
        xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xcell In frange
            c.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(c.Formula, Len(c.Formula) - 1) & ","" & xStr & "")"
        Next xcell
    End If
    Set frange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `c.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(c.Formula, 2) & ",""" & xStr & """)"`

Comment: Thankyou but it doesnt work.

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: it gives an error and debug screen pops up

Comment: c.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(c.Formula, Len(c.Formula) - 1) & ","" & xStr & "")"    the issue is in this line. I have tried yours but it isn't working

Comment: I tested my code before posting and it works fine, but note Christian's comments below about the rest of your code!

Comment: My code had several errors. Yours one was working perfectly fine. Thankyou for assisting me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code and all of them are because you are not using `Option Explicit`. If you did, you would immediately see that you are using the incorrect variables.

The `ws` variable is never declared or assigned. So you should change:

```
Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

to:

```
Set frange = frange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

which also is not a good idea because if there are no formulas the `frange` remains as the original selection (error is ignored). So, it's better (and easier to read) if you have 2 separate ranges. One for the initial selection and one for the formulas.

`xUpdate` is also never declared and moreover you never use it to restore the state of the `Application.ScreenUpdating` back to what it was.

There is no `c` variable. You loop iterator is called `xcell` so using `c.Formula` makes no sense unless you actually intended `xcell.Formula`.

Finally you should do what @Rory suggested (part of it) and replace `","" & xStr & "")"` with `",""" & xStr & """)"` so that the actual value of `xStr` is concatenated.

Also, you might want to restrict the number of times you can apply `IFERROR` to the same cell because if you run your procedure a couple of times on the same selection you will end up with something like `=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(...` which might not be what you want.

I would also rename the variables to more meaningful names. For example I would rename `xAddress` to `currentSelectionAddress`.

All of the above can be summed up in:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_IFERROR()
    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim formulaRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim currentSelectionAddress As String
    Dim blankReplacement As String
    Dim appScreenUpdate As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next
    currentSelectionAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set selectedRange = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", "Kutools for Excel", currentSelectionAddress, Type:=8)
    Set formulaRange = selectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If formulaRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    blankReplacement = Application.InputBox("Replace blank cells with what?", "Kutools for Excel")
    appScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In formulaRange
        cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1) & ",""" & blankReplacement & """)"
    Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = appScreenUpdate
End Sub
```

I do not understand why you're asking the user to replace blank cells because your code does no check to see if the formulas return a blank value. I was thinking that you are replacing errors rather than blanks so maybe you should update `"Replace blank cells with what?"` with `"Replace error cells with what?"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never tried VBA coding before so i was trying to some codes together to make a module i needed. That is why it had so many errors. Replace blank cells with was due to pasting code from another module.

Comment: @Malikh1517 Good luck with your project! Definitely turn on ```Option Explicit``` via the VBA editor (Tools\Option\Editor\Require Variable Declaration) so that the compiler warnings are helping you figure things out. Since you are new to the site, consider marking my answer as the accepted answer or maybe even upvote it by pressing the up arrow on the top-left of the answer. I am not saying this so that I get the reputation points but because if you are using this site you should get in the habit of upvoting and  accepting answers to reward the people making the effort to respond.

Comment: Also it's quite possible that more people would answer the same question and so the number of upvotes on each answer would make the best answer surface to the top where it can help more people besides the OP (original poster).

Comment: I can't upvote at this stage cause my reputation is below 15,  And yes! your answer was useful.  I made my account today and for the purpose of above module cause i wasn't able to figure out the errors in my code. Assistance by you helped me a lot.